# why CATALINA_OPTS arguments shows up in java process on running tomcat even though its an environment variable

Tags: tomcat, java

I run tomcat process by this command in python :

```
os.execve(cmd, [cmd, "run"], env)
```

The env variable sets `CATALINA_OPTS = -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Xss512k`
Now when i run the script following java process is shown in ps output :

```
java -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Xss512k org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

My question is why CATALINA_OPTS getting shown up in ps output of java process even though CATALINA_OPTS is an environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Typically the [catalina.sh](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/bin/catalina.sh.shtml) script is invoked via a wrapper as a [sysvinit](http://www.raibledesigns.com/tomcat/boot-howto.html) script. It loads the environment variable and uses it as an argument to the java process that ultimately calls tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I opened `catalina.sh` script to read the code :

Found this line :

```
eval "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
```

The `catalina.sh` script invokes a java process passing `$CATALINA_OPTS` arguments to the java process.